# Is it possible to detect and notifies the user's gps when came near to other user ? android:windows app

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, gps

My project idea is to create a `GPS locator` of friends when they come into particular range. Is it possible to detects other `GPS devices` and drawing shortest routes between them? Here if it detects mutually users or contact holder, then it notifies. I have code for displaying single user `geoLocation`.  I am going to include `xmpp` to chat online. this app is like social apps. I know that user's GPS will be on for a time and off GPS through code. Is it possible to accomplish? If yes, give some main works to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://parse.com/.

They support storing location objects in relation to a user or installation. The location objects allows queries such as `query.whereNear("location", userLocation);`, see https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#geo for details.

Furthermore you can send push notifications to both android and windows phones using their system, which could be neat for the chat part.

Comment: thank you and any other is there to create xmpp rather than Quickblox. Sir Can you tell the following steps to create and complete these type of apps which is internet oriented -Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry I do not have any direct experience with xmpp or Quickblox.